# How to escape everything in a block in HTML

Tags: html, escaping

I seem to recall that there is an HTML tag that escapes absolutely everything inside it except the matching closing tag. Kind of like [`<plaintext>`](http://www.htmlref.com/reference/AppA/tag_plaintext.htm) but not fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<xmp> is the tag you are looking for:

```
<xmp>some stuff <tags></tags> too</xmp>
```

But, since it's depricated, the best you can get is <pre>.

Comment: Sweet! I've been wanting a tag like this!

Comment: <xmp> is deprecated -- it should not be used.  See http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_XMP.html.

Comment: Unfortunately `<xmp>` can't properly escape string like this `<xmp></xmp>`, very close, but no. I haven't found anything better than `<plaintext>`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `<pre><code> ... </code></pre>`.

`<xmp>` is deprecated and should not be used.  See http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_XMP.html.

Comment: Ditto Mohit. just tested that with a html document in side <pre><code>, FF2 gave a blank screen

Comment: http://www.htmlref.com/Reference/AppA/tag_xmp.htm seems that it works most places (and what better can you get with HTML anyway?)

Answer (score 1):

There is also the XML [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_cdata.asp):

```
<![CDATA[stuff that is <tag>never</tag> parsed]]>
```

Whether this works in an HTML document is probably up to the browser. However, it should certainly work in an XHTML document.

Comment: Can it also escape its closing part `]]>` ?