# How to show html source code in html page

Tags: html, pre

I want to display html code in html,I tried [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html) from SO itself, but that was not helpful or may be I'm missing something. Then, I tried following syntax, but not helpful (only getting **Click Here to Apply**).

```
<pre><code><span style='font-size:20px'>Click Here to Apply </span></code></pre>
```

Anyone help me to figure out, what's wrong in my approach ?

Comment: Is your code being generated dynamically?

Comment: no, i'm writing that code in html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display HTML code in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html)

Comment: Please read ALL answers and comments in the linked question

Comment: @Pumbaa80 but I think I followed all the answers and comment from that post. And, as OP of that post included same problem as I pointed here too that **replacing each `<` and `>` chars to `&lt;` and `&gt;` isn't seems to be efficient solution** Also, in my second approach shows, I even tried `<pre><code>` too, but that also not helpful.

Comment: The answers clearly state that you have to escape the contents of `<pre><code>`, but you don't need to escape the contents of `<textarea>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tomer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18040470/361684) is correct and that is the way that I would do it.  But there is an alternative that uses JavaScript.  You can remove the HTML of an element, and add it back as text using `createTextNode()`.  Pass an element to this function:

```
function revealElementHTML(el) {
    var html = el.innerHTML;
    el.innerHTML = "";
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(html));
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/rh7RW](http://jsfiddle.net/rh7RW/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace all '<' characters with `&lt;` and all '>' with `&gt;`

Note this won't provide code coloring though if that's what you seek.

Comment: i don't code coloring, what i want is, it should display code part instead of displaying only text part

Comment: then try this.  you cant use the '<' char even not in a <code> tag.

Comment: @Tomer You can add html code to an answer by either putting it between backticks or by indenting it with 4 spaces.

Comment: but replacing each `<` and `>` chars to `&lt;` and `&gt;` isn't seems to be efficient solution.

Comment: That is the standard html syntax for those characters when they are to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be an `xmp` tag to support this - this tag is **now deprecated** but is still supported by all major browsers.

You can use it if nothing else suits your needs.

```
<pre><xmp><span style='font-size:20px'>Click Here to Apply </span></xmp></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you require colorized snippests, 
jQuery.snippest offers a nice colorize tool.

http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/

Answer (score 0):

you should use the ascii characters to show your code or you have to use javascript as on gilly3's answer.

you can convert your html code [online](http://www.freebits.co.uk/convert-html-code-to-text.html).

If you use php, use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

finally you can use following css to style it.

```
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have try all of them, the pre/code is not really solution, but we have other 3 simple solution

1. textarea

```html
<textarea name="tex" id="texa" cols="30" rows="10"class="one textarea">
        here is ok, mama? <a href="#">aoeueouoe</a> 

</textarea>
```

```js
texa.value+='<br>\n\n'+i;
```

2. xmp

```xml
<xmp>
    keyi1xiedaimama? <a href="#">aoeueouoe</a>      
</xmp>
```

3. createTextNode

```js
info.appendChild(document.createTextNode(texa.value));
```