# How show html codes just like codes in html pages

Tags: html, format

I want to show code like "code" in HTML : [note : unlimited code can use]

Example:
        ‹img src='#' title='demo title'›‹/img›
i used `<code>` or `<pre>` but they both did not work

i dont want to used php, jquery or java script code.
Just html codes just like pre or code tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display HTML code in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tag xmp which is Depreciated one, but still works . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp.

```
<xmp>‹img src='#' title='demo title'›‹/img›</xmp>
```

**OR**

keep your code in a textarea inside a form, like:

```
   <form>
     <textarea>
       ‹img src='#' title='demo title'›‹/img›
    </textarea>
   </form>
```

**OR** (recommended)

you can use pre tag with code tag:

```
 <pre>
   <code>‹img src='#' title='demo title'›‹/img›</code>
 </pre>
```

Comment: i said pre now worked because need escaped charchters ,i dont want use escaped charachters - here http://jsfiddle.net/barnameha/hF985/ how can delete vertical space between two xmp tags?(i used style margins:0px;padding:0px but not worked

Comment: pre code with inline code tag not worked u can see (http://jsfiddle.net/barnameha/xdwB5/)

Comment: i edited my jsfiddle and worked i added style http://jsfiddle.net/barnameha/hF985/1/ thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to escapse the string:

```
<code>&lt;img src='#' title='demo title'&gt;&lt;/img&gt;</code>
```

Escapse HTML Entities: 
http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html

Comment: i want dont use any links for convert because i designed a chat windows , i want user when typed any codes shows results just like codes not executed code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CDATA section

like this :

```
<![CDATA[Your <code> here]]>
```

Comment: CDATA sections are only supported in browsers when parsing `application/xhtml+xml` (and other XML) documents. I'm not aware of any browser that supports them in `text/html` documents.

Comment: so your answer is not good because i dont want used for application/xhtml+xml format i want used just like html

Answer (score 0):

```
&lt;img src='#' title='demo title'&gt;&lt;/img&gt;
```

Easier with PHP: http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: With the php-command I posted. `<?php echo htmlspecialchars("Your Code"); ?>`

Answer (score -1):

```
<code>&lsaquo;img src='#' title='demo title'&rsaquo;&lsaquo;/img&rsaquo;<code>
```

just copy paste the code you will get what  you want

O/P:-

```
<img src='#' title='demo title'></img>
```