# Showing html code as text in html webpage

Tags: html, razor

I'm asking on how could we show html code on a tutorial html website, for example to show to user how to make a link?

```
<a href="#">text</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html

Comment: @clement put the code between `<xmp> </xmp>` tags. P.S. XMP is deprecated ;)

Comment: It you need to ask, are you qualified to write an HTML tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CDATASection.
The CDATASection object represents a CDATA section in a document.

A CDATA section contains text that will NOT be parsed by a parser. Tags inside a CDATA section will NOT be treated as markup and entities will not be expanded.

You can use it in XML for sample :

```
<![CDATA[<tag>Some text</tag>]]>
```

It Will interpreted such as :

```
&lt;tag&gt;some text&lt;/tag&gt;
```

Or in program Output. Sample with CSS :

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
body { background:black;  }     
/*]]>*/
</style>
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 4):

Use HTML [entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) for it.

E.g.:

- `&lt;` for <
- `&gt;` for >

`<pre>`, `<code>` or `<xmp>` can be used but have compatibility issue.

Example:

1. `&lt;a href="#"&gt;text&lt;/a&gt;`
2. `<span class="code"><span class="lt">&lt;</span>a href="#"<span class="gt">&gt;</span>text<span class="lt">&lt;</span><span class="fs">/</span>a<span class="gt">&gt;</span></span>`

CSS for Example 2:

```
.code {
    font-family:Courier;
    color:#DF42AA;
}
.lt, .gt, .fs{
    font-family:Courier;
    color:#032F82;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

replace < by `&lt;` and > by `&gt;`

Answer (score 2):

An other way with CSS :

```
code::before { content:'<'; }
code::after { content:'>'; }
```

And then, your HTML code will be :

```
<code>a href="#"</code>text<code>/a</code>
```

From [this website about CSS](http://stylescss.free.fr/v2-tricks/tags.php) (but in french).

Answer (score 0):

use

`&lt;` for `<`
and
`&gt;` for `>`

A shortcut is "if you use `&lt;` for `<`,and don't use `&gt;` for `>`,
then your output will be same as using both `&lt;` and `&gt`.