# "language-markup" HTML Syntax Display in Markdown

Tags: html, markdown

Trying to submit a blog entry in Markdown. The entry includes a section displaying HTML syntax. However, when I try to include it in the markdown file, the HTML is getting rendered in the page itself.

How do I get it to just display the syntax without rendering?

This is what I'm trying now:

```
<pre class=" language-markup"><code class=" language-markup">
    <p>Blah</p>
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: you're going to have to use the entity characters

Comment: also please look for your quesiton on SO first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already seen this answer but it hardly seems practical to convert every < and > with &lt and &gt. Also the answer was from 2010. 

And I'm trying their last option of wrapping things in <pre> and <code> tags but it doesnt seem to work. 

Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you put the HTML in a code block, the angle brackets will get converted for you. Any reason you can't just use a code block?

Comment: @Waylan. Sorry, if I'm missing something, but isn't that what I'm doing already?

Comment: I mean code blocks using Markdown syntax, not HTML... Indent the block by four spaces. See the [rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode).

Comment: Ah @Waylan.  Yeah... I ended up doing that, but I wasn't able to take advantage of the syntax highlighting used on the site. Thanks for the input. At least I know that there wasn't something obvious I wasn't doing.