# Use <code> or similar tags in ReactJS using JSX

Tags: html, reactjs, blockquote

I am trying to use ReactJS with JSX to create a proof of concept for a styleguide.

I wanted to be able to display the raw html of how to call on components doing this. JSX is ignoring my `<code>` tags and rendering out the component

This is what i have tried so far 
[Display HTML code in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html)

```js
<blockquote>
  <pre>
    <code>
      <VideoPlayer 
        ref="videoplayer" 
        preload={this.props.preload} 
        classes={this.props.classes} 
        videoID={this.props.videoID}
        controls="controls" 
      />     
    </code>
  </pre>
</blockquote>
```

I was surprised to see it render.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson how do I expose the jsx markup so it doesn't render a component and shows just the tags. This would allow others to see how the component can be implemented

Comment: The tag <code> wasn't supposed to do nothing more than change font style, even if you try to use it outside of JSX it doesn't render the tags, just the text. I Thing you will need a external lib to render code as you see here in github.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want that code as literal block, you'll need to use JSX-safe characters, so either JSX-escape everything, or use HTML entities where you can and then you still need to JSX-escape the curly brackets (because those are templating syntax in JSX) and newlines (yes, those newlines are not JSX-safe, either. Whitespace is collapsed during JSX transformation).

And you probably want to use a `<pre>`, which is a block-level element for formatted text, rather than `<code>`, which is inline:

```
<pre>
  &lt;VideoPlayer{'\n'}
    ref="videoplayer"{'\n'}
    preload={'{'}this.props.preload{'}\n'}
    classes={'{'}this.props.classes{'}\n'}
    videoID={'{'}this.props.videoID{'}\n'}
    controls="controls"{'\n'}
  /&gt;</pre>
```

"That's so much work O_o", yeah it is. So usually you don't bother doing this yourself; if you use a bundler, you use a preprocessor (like [block-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/block-loader) if you're using webpack), or if you don't you often use a special react component that renders text verbatim.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your the man. This is a proof of concept that i am trying to hack together rapidly.  You just saved me hours of time!!!!

Answer (score 25):

In your example, react interprets your code as JSX.  You need to use JSX-save coding.  The easiest is to include a string literal:

```
<pre>{`
  <VideoPlayer 
    ref="videoplayer" 
    preload={this.props.preload} 
    classes={this.props.classes} 
    videoID={this.props.videoID}
    controls="controls" 
  />
`}</pre>
```

Explanation:  Parsing your input starts at `<pre>` in JSX mode.  The opening bracket `{` switches the parser into JavaScript mode to include computed values into the output. Now the backquote ` switches the parser into string-parsing mode. This can span multiple lines.  Inside string parsing mode, JSX-special characters `<>{}` are not special anymore.  But you must escape the two characters that are special inside multi-line strings: The back quote ` and the dollar sign $.

After parsing your coding, the final back quote switches back to JavaScript mode, the following `}` switches back to JSX mode and `</pre>` completes your element.

React will automatically convert your string into safe HTML.