# Is there a better way of outputting multiple lines of example code when using jsx?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to output a block of example code as it is. Not HTML code i want to output javascript. I don't want the code rendered. I just want to show an example of how to do something. So for example I want this to be on my page:

```
if(a==b){ 
   console.log('a is the same as b)
}
```

I have been researching online and the only option I can find is to surround it with {``}. However, this creates a problem that I have to include spaces and breaks manually like this:

```
{`if(a==b){`}
<br />
{`\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0console.log('a is the same as b)`}
<br />
{`}`}
```

As you can see for a large block of example code this can get very cumbersome. Does anyone know a better way of outputting a larger block of example code using jsx?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use <code> or similar tags in ReactJS using JSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932063/use-code-or-similar-tags-in-reactjs-using-jsx)

Comment: That post is refering to outputting html code. I want to know for javascript or other code.

Comment: ???? it's the same principle

Comment: I may be wrong but in my opinion its not because in html code you can add <br />. I'm asking how to do this for javascript code without having to add them manually in at the end like in my example. Also the indentation can be added inside the html tags but I need at present to add \u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0 to indent the code when it is rendered. This is a pain and I want to know is there a better way. I'm not asking about escaping the special characters I'm asking about the breaks and indentation being included upon rendering. I hope that clears up the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const App = () => (
  <pre>{`
          if(a==b){ 
            console.log('a is the same as b)
          }
      `}
    </pre>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can use the PRE tag.

> The HTML pre element (or HTML Preformatted Text) represents preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in a non-proportional ("monospace") font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as typed.

Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

```
    <pre>{`
          if(a==b){ 
            console.log('a is the same as b)
          }
      `}
    </pre>
```

[image]