# Treating child HTML as a string and as HTML in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm trying to create a component that both shows the result of some HTML that includes other components and shows the code itself. Basically, a container that demos the markup and shows what markup was used *with child components intact*. The problem I'm having is that I can only seem to get the fully rendered HTML to display as code when I want he literal input that hasn't been resolved and still includes any component tags that have been used.

```
<ParentComponent>
    <div></div>
    <ChildComponent></ChildComponent>
    <div></div>
</ParentComponent>
```

I'd like the ParentComponent to both fully render all of its children, but also treat all HTML within it as a string, essentially, ideally without maintaining two copies of the children. The rendered version is no problem, that happens naturally, but the string form I can't seem to grab from anywhere, it gets the rendered version where ChildComponent is replaced by what it renders as.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use <code> or similar tags in ReactJS using JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932063/use-code-or-similar-tags-in-reactjs-using-jsx)

Comment: @mccambridge Not quite a duplicate because I'm trying to **both** render and display as code with one instance. I know how to show it literally, but I want one component that treats it in two different ways without having to maintain two versions of the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this should work for your use case.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import jsxToString from 'jsx-to-string';

const ParentComponent = props => (
  <div>
    {`I'm a ParentComponent`} 
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
const ChildComponent = () => <div>{`I'm a ChildComponent`}</div>;

const getParent = () => <ParentComponent>
  <div />
  <ChildComponent />
  <div />
</ParentComponent>;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {getParent()}
      {jsxToString(getParent())}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Give it a try.

Comment: This did the job! I now have a container component that renders children once then shows them as a string underneath, just as I wanted.