# add html (for a copyable embed code) that displays as string not html

Tags: c#, html

My website produces and object that I would like to allow my users to "embed" - I have an api url for retrieving parameters etc. - however, when I try to write the embed code to a label it simply shows an embed object, rather than the code.

How can I just return the html code as a string, rather than as html so the user sees the code, not the object? (Using c#)

### edit

Just clarifying per the request - I am expecting the user to see embed code: i.e. the string: "<" embed src='myAPIURL?thispageID' height='300' width='800'>" but instead that object is being embedded in the page.

I'm writing to to a label at present.

Comment: Can you be more specific, like with an example of what the user should see, versus what they actually see at the moment?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was clear. The user should see <embed src='myapiurl' height='300' width='800'></embed> in a copyable format. Instead they see the actual object from myapiurl embedded in the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display HTML code in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html)

Comment: @TimTroiano thanks - I had done a lot of searching but didn't find that one. (Found the opposite problem of people wanting to know how to put html in Literals etc.) But the solution in that duplicate question works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape '<' and '>' with `“&lt;”` and `“&gt;”`

Comment: that didn't work as i was putting in a label, but the &lt; and &gt; escape works fine