# How to include html code inside a html document?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

what i want to do is like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target

but the html that will be send on iframe will be the HTMLBody of an msg file.

**What I have tried:**

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">
<label>sample</label>
<button>send</button>
</div>
<div id="2ndHTML">
   (Insert html codes without replacing the above tags)
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
MailItem item = (MailItem)app.CreateItemFromTemplate(@"C:\Users\elayronj\Desktop\Sample\sample.msg", Type.Missing);

samplediv.InnerHtml = item.HTMLBody;
```

Comment: Why not just type them there? Are you trying to do this programmatically? Can you show the code if so?

Comment: @JohnPaul - flagged as not-constructive.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html. Question should be marked as a dupilcate.

Comment: @YacoubMassad pls see default.aspx.cs for the code. Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the template to include some value (e.g. a GUID) in the place where you want to insert the new HTML?

Comment: It's still not clear to me if you're wanting to *display HTML within an HTML email*, or if you're wanting to *inject HTML into a template* (that maybe has the company logo, a standard footer, etc.) to construct a HTML email message. Could you clarify for us? Also, what is the type of `samplediv` in the code snippet? How is it created?

Comment: what i want to do is like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target

but the html that will be send on iframe will be the HTMLBody of an msg file.

Answer (score 0):

The **deprecated** `<xmp>` tag can be used to show HTML code inside an HTML page but **is no longer part of the XHTML spec**. It should still work though in all current browsers.

See this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/btxkLud6/)

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp)

> The HTML Example Element () renders text between the start and
>   end tags without interpreting the HTML in between and using a
>   monospaced font. The HTML2 specification recommended that it should be
>   rendered wide enough to allow 80 characters per line.

As said in the docs,

The `<xmp>` tag has been deprecated since HTML3.2 and was not implemented in a consistent way. It was completely removed from the language in HTML5 and to achieve the functionality, you can use

- the `<pre>` element or, if semantically adequate, the `<code>`
  element instead. Note that you will need to escape the '<' character
  as '<' to make sure it is not interpreted as markup.
- A monospaced font can also be obtained on any element, by applying an
  adequate CSS style using monospace as the generic-font value for the
  font-family property.

Comment: isn't the output of the tags inside xmp is in all text?

Comment: sorry...didnt get you..

Comment: why is the answer downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm pretty sure the the guy is asking just how to escape < and >, not how to use an esoteric feature.

Comment: yeah ok..understood..but please do read my answer fully..I've explained to him, how he has to do it..without just blindly giving some links that will do the work for him..I think I was right in giving that answer..Some people get a little bit irritated when they see the word **deprecated** and they just downvotes..Anyway, thanks @MatthewMartin for taking time to read my answer..

Comment: @Lal - things are deprecated for a reason.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ could you please explain to me, the reason why the tag is deprecated..

Comment: @Lal - why? You've missed the point. It is deprecated, i.e. not supported - and strongly recommended that nobody chooses to use it going forward. So why answer a question with a suggestion to use it? Also, forget about the fact it's deprecated - it's horrible. For another dev approaching extensive use of this tag - it becomes increasingly complex to draw the line between mark-up and xmp content. Your jsFiddle demonstrates this nicely.

Comment: Sorry @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ you are totally mistaken..AS you can see in my answer, I've told the OP that the deprecated tag could have solved his issue and since its deprecated he have to use some other tags in-order to achieve the functionality..Still dont understand where I'm wrong..Is it just because I have used the word "deprecated" ?

Comment: I quote - "It should still work though in all current browsers. See this working fiddle". If that's not suggesting to use it I don't know what is.

Comment: That is what is true @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ ...Is saying truth in SO such a big crime?

Comment: @Lal - don't be dramatic

Comment: really awkward @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ ..