# Parse string into HTML

Tags: python, html, jinja2, html-encode

I'm trying to recreate a blog CRUD application in which a user can create posts by inputting text into a `textarea` of a `<form>`. From here the input is stored in Postgresql as the type `text` for later use. I'd like to parse that string of text into HTML.

### The issue I am having:

User inputs a string of what would be formatted into HTML. The program would take this string and format it into raw HTML.

### What input is expected:

```
<h2>Title here</h2>
<p>some text here</p>
```

### What is should be formatted to:

### Title here

some text here

### How it is displayed:

```
&lt;h2&gt;Title here &lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;p&gt;some text here &lt;/p&gt;
```

### What I have done:

I've read about using a WYSIWYG text editors like CKEditor and TinyMCE. I even used CKEditor but when I save the input into the database it's rendered as a string not the HTML I want, which makes sense. I've also used modules such as HTML5lib, html and BeautifulSoup but it's still rendering as `'<h2>Title here</h2><p>some text here</p>'` with the single quotations. So it's still a string. I want to escape the first and last quotes but not every single one between.

Basically I am trying to reproduce this very text editor on Stackoverflow. I am storing the input as a Postgresql `text` data type. I figured it's optimal to format the string into HTML when it is retrieved from the database, and not before it is stored (wrong?). I have even implemented a class to do so, like:

```
class Post():
  body = db.Column(db.Text)

def to_html(self, body):
  '''format string of chars to HTML. Return HTML'''
  # ...
```

Then in the html template I could (I'm using Jinja to do this):

```
{{ Post.to_html(body) }}
```

I believe I am confused about encoding/decoding text and html.

Comment: i think you are confused cus you're confusing me.... you realize that HTML **is** a string...

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand a bit about html... What you have is raw HTML:

```
<h2>Title here</h2><p>some text here</p>
```

Save that in a blank file with a .htm extension, then open it with a browser. The browser interprets the raw HTML and gives you the formatted output you want.

I suggest you read [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html) before continuing with your project.

Comment: the text is stored into Postgresql as the type `text` under the table Post in the row `Post.body`. It isn't stored as a file. When I extract the data in `Post.body` and place it into an html template it comes out, for example, like `&lt;h2&gt;here is some text &lt;/h2&gt;` but it suppose to be rendered as <h2>here is some text</h2> (but here its formatted without the tags)

Comment: Storing html as text/string is fine... That's all html is. You don't need to worry about how it looks until you display it to a user.

Comment: Are you looking at your result in a browser? You're not going to get formatted text in whatever shell you're using.

Comment: Yes I'm using a browser and using the browsers dev tool

Comment: ok... so, you're escaping <> with &lt; and &gt; but its converting them back so that the browser sees &lt;h2&gt; as <h2> and displays "here is some text" as a heading. Correct?

Comment: check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html), it might solve your problem. You might also try wrapping your code samples in <pre> and <code> tags.

Comment: In the html it looks like this `<div>&lt;h2&gt;Some h2 text&lt;/h2&gt;</div>` where `&lt;h2&gt;Some h2 text&lt;/h2&gt;` should be `<h2>Some h2 text</h2>`. In the browser it shows `<h2>Some h2 text</h2>` NOT as a H2 heading but in non-heading text.