# How to do i get html to display on page instead of running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, innerhtml

My problem seems to be the opposite of the problem most other people have. I do not want HTML in the .innerHTML to run. I want it to display on the page as is. (I know there is another problem in my code. I'm working on that)

https://jsfiddle.net/ojfykv17/
or

```
<div id="code">

</div>
```

```js
    function genorateCode() {
      var account = document.getElementById("account");
        var url = document.getElementById("url");
        sendCode();
    }
    function sendCode() {
    document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = '<a href="'+url+'">'+'<div class="button"><img src="https://s15.postimg.org/mfpd2ki8r/icon.png" width="16">@'+account+'</div></a>';
    }
    sendCode();
```

```css
    .button {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    border:1;
    border-style: solid;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border-width: 1.2px;
    line-height: 5px; 
    border-color: #a5aab1;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input type="text" id="account" />
        <input type="text" id="url" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="genorateCode();" />
    </form>
    
    <div id="code">
    
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't want it to run? Do you mean you want it to actually display the markup tags? If so, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html

Comment: Here's a working version using a `<textarea>`: https://jsfiddle.net/nq5qLvwu/

Comment: @IanEmnace - I think you can substitute "interpreted" — as in _"I do not want HTML in the .innerHTML to be interpreted"_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting `innerHTML`, set the `innerText` of the element.

```
document.getElementById('code').innerText = '<a href="'+url+ ...
```

Comment: Obligatory note on [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=innertext). Also check the linked [article](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/).

Comment: That is a good article and I recommend anyone finding this answer reads it!

Answer (score 4):

You will need to convert all the HTML tags from `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Otherwise the browser will render it as HTML.

Comment: Escaping `>` is not necessary if `<` is already escaped.

Answer (score 2):

There is couple of things need to edit in your code. The first function having local variable `account` and `url`, and after that you accessing it inside second function which is of course not in it scope.

```
var account,url;

function genorateCode() {
  // are you sure you want this document.getElementById("account")
  // instead if this -> document.getElementById("account").value ???
  account = document.getElementById("account").value;
  url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  sendCode();
}
```

And in your case, you can use insertAdjacentHTML like follow :

```
function sendCode() {  
  var str = '<a href="' + url + '">' + '<div class="button"><img src="https://s15.postimg.org/mfpd2ki8r/icon.png" width="16">@' + account + '</div></a>';
  document.getElementById('code').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/259ddpze/)