# I want to show code in html page

Tags: html

I want to show code in a html page. The code may be written in any language.The output should be as follows:

[image: The output will be like this.]

Comment: Ok. What's your question? Something more specific than "how do I do this?" I hope.

Comment: This question has already been answered endless times. Take a look here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html

Comment: How to implement this?

Comment: Google e.g. `html code highlighting`. It'll give you a number of solutions, e.g. https://highlightjs.org. Even a query for `I want to show code in html page` gets good results - always remember to Google first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is write up some CSS (or use inline styling) for the grey background div and then use `<span>` tags to color the text inside of a `<p>` tag.

Here is some info on span tags: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

Also, you have to replace some characters in the code you want to display. You should replace `<` with &lt, and replace `>`  with &gt. You can put all of that inside of a `<code>` tag if you would like, but I don't think its necessary.

If you would like it to automatically be colored and formatted and such, then you may need some JavaScript or something, but if it is a static HTML page, then you should just stick with the basics.