# HTML input: howto preserve &quot; as it is instead of convert to "

Tags: html, input, escaping, quotes

I'm wondering how to keep `&quot;` as it is, instead of it being converted to `"` when used as an input value? Example:

```html
<input type="text" value="&quot;a">
```

Comment: You need to HTML encode the value so that it becomes `&amp;quot;a`. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code to learn how to format code examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html | you should add what you tried.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, so is there a solution? when i click on "Run code snippet", I need the input value shown as "& quot;a" (no space), not "a

Comment: The first sentence in my previous comment.