# How to run highlight.js on JS Fiddle

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I am working on [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/nzubL391/). Why am I not able to run Highcharts.js on the JS Fiddle?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(e)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the `$(document).ready(function() {` call.  You can view the syntax error you are getting in the developer console of your browser.

Here is a fixed code block for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(e)
  });
 }); // this is the missing closing });
```

Comment: Thanks tomato, but this is still not working https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/nzubL391/1/

Comment: I'm able to see a highlight box around the content, what functionality are you looking for or missing?

Comment: I can see the box too but how about syntax highlighting? Looks like page is rendering the tags instead of displaying the code

Comment: In order to display the code you will have to escape the < > characters.  Here is another stack overflow page with more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html