# Display HTML code in text box

Tags: html, css

I am having a text box which I am filling from the Json response as below

```
 <div class="gadget-body" style="height:100px">
    <label>{{ textData}}</label>
  </div>
```

But now my Json is returning html code with `<p>` and `<h1>` tags. I am binding the response, but it is displaying with `<p>` and `<h1>` tags instead of applying it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display HTML code in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html)

Comment: @ISHIDA removing space doesn't help

Comment: @Strernd I saw the link, but my case is different. I am using Angular2 and my Json response has html tags, which I need to convert and show it.

Comment: @phani1382 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding

Comment: Give a id to your label and use innerHtml using that id and bind it. @techLove gave an example of it.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and easiest way is use innerhtml tag

```
<div class="gadget-body" >
   <div [innerHTML]="textData">
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a function like this :

```
function htmlToPlaintext(text) {
  return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
}
```

and then you'd use:

```
<div class="gadget-body" style="height:100px">
    <label>{{ htmlToPlaintext(textData) }}</label>
</div>
```