# How to escape HTML inside <span> or <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

```
<h4>    
  <span class="title">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> How are you. </textarea>
  </span>
</h4>
```

How to consider `<textarea rows="4" cols="50"> How are you. </textarea>` as a string and not HTML. I don't want HTML to render, I just want whatever comes into div or span it should render.

EXPECTED RESULT : `<textarea rows="4" cols="50"> How are you. </textarea>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html

Comment: @Parag Bhingre the comment above is very descriptive about escaping html tags in html and my answer is relevant as well. Did those solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the html you want to show

```
&lt; is <
&quot; is ""
&gt; is >
```

> There is an online tool that can do this for you [here](http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html), but you can find many scripts that can do it for in runtime.

```html
<h4>    
<span class="title">
&lt;textarea rows=&quot;4&quot; cols=&quot;50&quot;&gt; How are you. &lt;/textarea&gt;
</span>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery just use text() instead of html() to insert the code:

```js
$('span').text('<textarea rows="4" cols="50"> How are you. </textarea>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h4>    
<span class="title"></span>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JavaScript, without any library, you can use a function to insert the code as a text node in some container.

```js
function insertAsText( containerId, text ) {
    var container = document.getElementById( containerId );
    var textNode = document.createTextNode( text );
    container.appendChild( textNode );
}

insertAsText( "myDiv", "<p><textarea>test</textarea></p>");
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerHTML = "<div>HI!</div>";
//Result will be "HI!"
document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerText = "<div>HI!</div>";
//Result will be "<div>HI!</div>"
```

JQuery:

```
$(".title").html("<div>HI!</div>");
//Result will be "HI!"
$(".title").text("<div>HI!</div>");
//Result will be "<div>HI!</div>"
```

As a final comment, those ways are get/set.

Answer (score 0):

I just added an ID to the target `textarea` for convenience:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('txtArea'));
```

```html
<h4>
  <span class="tip" 4 "=" cols="50" original-title="title"> Hi hello 
<span class="title"><textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtArea"> How are you. </textarea></span>
  </span>
</h4>
```

Comment: Hey tommy thanks for quick response. I actually want to print textarea tag and string as is. I do not want textarea to appear.

Comment: We can not add id to textarea because the data within span is dynamic. next time <b>TOMMY</b> this kinda string can also come. So i dont want to make it bold, I just want to print string as is.