# How can I quickly capture a websites MathML to use in Word?

Tags: mathjax, mathml

I create mathematics workbooks in Microsoft Word. Typing in each equation is slow but faster than LaTex. So, I often copy content from a website like [LibreTexts](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Map%3A_Calculus_-_Early_Transcendentals_(Stewart)/12%3A_Vectors_and_The_Geometry_of_Space/12.05%3A_Equations_of_Lines_and_Planes). If I copy a section that contains equations it comes out garbled. So, I go to each equation, right click, hover over Show Math As, select MathML code, select all (Ctrl+a), copy (ctrl+c), close window (Ctrl+w), go to word (Alt-Tab), paste as plain text (Ctrl+Shift+v), go back to Chrome browser (Alt-Tab), then repeat the process.

This can be faster than typing by hand, but there has to be an easier way. There was a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709187/browser-to-display-mathml-code-instead-of-equation?newreg=3904d93ba0554a41a0e0f01acd240c6b) similar to this one, but I don't know what extension was referred to and I don't know java.

If your solutions contains the step "learn basic Java here", that is fine. If this is the incorrect Stack Exchange, please suggest the correct one.

Thank you.