# Force browser to display Element as text

Tags: css, html, web, browser

I got this weird problem:
I get content that is dynamically built. In this special case I also get the element "input" as content, which is then displayed directly by the browser as an element.

**What I get:**

```
<div class="search_result_content"> this is just text, but the code <input variable="" name=""> displays as an element
```

[image]

**What i need:**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display HTML code in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html)

Comment: You need to replace "<input" with "&lt;input"

Comment: thanks, that helped. @whbb

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add 'type="text"', so total would be like

```
<input type="text" name="" value=""/>
```

Else if the input needs to be added to a (like) 'span' or 'div', i would suggest JS or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search_result_content").append('<input variable="" name="">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search_result_content"> this is just text, but the code  </div>
```

u insert the input tag dynamically in this scenario, after inserting convert it into html format