# angular innerHTML doesn't show the json text like '<!DOCTYPE...'

Tags: angular, xss, innerhtml, angular-dom-sanitizer

Need some help with angular innerHTML and writing json data from server to HTML.

I have json with string like:

```
'<!DOCTYPE root [<!ENTITY % ext SYSTEM > %ext;]><br /><authorizationRequest login="1" password="1"></authorizationRequest>'
```

I'm trying to get in on HTML like:

```
[innerHTML]="selectedTask.description | safeHtml"
```

And have a pipe like:

```
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

transform(html) {
  console.log(html)
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}
```

And this trick does smth like:

'ext;]'

How can i have full safe string from json and write it in HTML

Comment: Do you want your HTML to be itnerpreted ? Because if so, know that you should not put doctypes in the middle of your HTML page, and params (I assume `%ext` are params) can't be displayed in Angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html

Comment: Why would you expect something starting with `<` to be *displayed* when explicitly say it should be treated as HTML? `<` is how you start a tag.

Comment: @Quentin Is there any opportunity to display it in HTML? It must be the desription of task, and i need to have in HTML everything that contains in json string

Comment: @Aragorn yeap, for instance, ive used smth like this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<xmp>${html}</xmp>`); and it works..now i need to know how it can be done for such cases

Comment: works better with <pre><code>${html}</code></pre>