# How can I render raw HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How can I render raw HTML?

For example, render **`<span>inner text</span>`** as is in `<div>Render this raw <span>inner text</span></div>`

Comment: what do you mean with render raw HTML? You need a programm that can read HTML like a browser. Or do you mean showing HTML codelines without having them parsed like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-snippets-in-html ?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: I assume you will need to pick a templating framework and use that. There are very very many choices. ReactJS is popular at the moment for client-side templating. For server-side, it depends on what backend you are using.