# how to display html code without rendering on page?

Tags: html

I want to display HTML code as it is without rendering.

**Current Output**

```
Note : Use
for Line Break.
```

**Expected Output**

```
Note : Use <br> for Line Break.
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Note : Use <br> for Line Break.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using a `<pre>`

Comment: @Pieterjan
I have tried but not working.

Comment: Does the html text come from a database or similar, or do you just want to show <br>? Otherwise you can use `&lt;br&gt;`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display HTML snippets in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-snippets-in-html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Method 1

---

You can use `<xmp>` but it's deprecated as suggested by @Someone_who_likes_SE. So probably avoid using it.

[Mozilla XMP Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) states:

> The  HTML element renders text between the start and end tags without interpreting the HTML in between and using a monospaced font.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <xmp>Note : Use <br> for Line Break.</xmp>
</body>
</html>
```

## Method 2

---

We generally replace the tag brackets with their HTML entities codes

`<` becomes `&lt;` and `>` becomes `&gt;`

```html
<html>
    <body>
      Note : Use &lt;br&gt; for Line Break.
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: XMP is deprecated as of HTML 3.2 and was **removed** in HTML 5. Don't use it.

Comment: I know its deprecated but <xmp> is the only thing that works if someone does not or cannot use &lt; etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can show HTML tags as plain text in HTML on a website or webpage by replacing `<` with `&lt;` or `&60;` and `>` with `&gt;` or `&62;` on each HTML tag that you want to be visible. Ordinarily, HTML tags are not visible to the reader on the browser.

Also you can look into this question:
[Display HTML snippets in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-snippets-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

```
Note : Use &lt;br&gt; for Line Break.
```