# PHP echo Not Outputting XML Characters

Tags: php, arrays, xml, get, echo

What's wrong with my PHP? I go to sandwiches.php?type=2 and all I see is cheeseavocadospinach, not the XML tags with the values.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
if ($_GET["type"] == "1")
  $sandwiches = array('ham', 'turkey', 'cheese');
if ($_GET["type"] == "2")
  $sandwiches = array('cheese', 'avocado', 'spinach');
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
echo '<sandwiches>';
foreach ($sandwiches as $value)
{
  echo '<sandwich>';
  echo $value;
  echo '</sandwich>';
}
echo '</sandwiches>';
?>
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the page source.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it, that's the point - your browser is showing you the text content, assuming the tags are just markup; view source, and you'll see the XML is there just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display HTML snippets in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-snippets-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

The XML characters show up when you view source.