# What is the correct way to use PRE or CODE tags with a OL list inside

Tags: html

The best way is to give an example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en">

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>PRE - CODE - OL test</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <PRE><CODE>
    <OL>
    <LI></LI>
    </OL>
    </CODE></PRE>
  <PRE>
    <OL>
    <LI></LI>
    </OL>
    </PRE>
  <CODE>
    <OL>
    <LI></LI>
    </OL>
    </CODE>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

The html validator tool returns:

```
":8.1-8.4: error: Element “ol” not allowed as child of element “code” in this context.
":12.6-13.4: error: Element “ol” not allowed as child of element “pre” in this context.
":18.1-18.4: error: Element “ol” not allowed as child of element “code” in this context.
```

Now, the document I'm creating displays exactly the way it should in Firefox and Edge, so I don't see a problem other than the syntax isn't valid HTML. So, how do I achieve the same result with valid HTML?

Edit: For those who want to see what my actual document looks like, [here](https://wayneca.neocities.org/Wolfenstein/source.html) is the link. Be aware, the document is over 100K in size.

---

Edit:

ksav provided the clues and help necessary to fix my issue. my document will now pass muster with the HTML validator. But there was one small issue that I had to find an answer to.

When I had a line such as:

```
// some code;
```

The // part had to be made blue to match what the page looked like before. Easy enough. The some code; part, though, was supposed to be red. Also easy enough. However, because I use spans to apply color to text not associated with any other tag to apply style to, a line number was being added to that part separately. This meant the displayed text looked like this:

```
25 // 26 some code;
```

Obviously, that is not the intended result. Well, the first thing I found was a way to keep the number on the red text from incrementing. That CSS is:

```
code>span:not(.spr) {
    counter-increment: listing;
}
```

That was a good start, as now the line numbers weren't incorrect, but there was still the issue of how to make the extra line number be invisible. Well, I found the answer. The CSS is:

```
.spr:before {
    content:none !important;
}
```

So, now my page displays the line correctly:

```
25 // some code;
```

Using this information, and the code that resulted from it, my above example can now be shown in a working manner. Note. .spr2 is for lines that are red but I still need a line number on them.

Edit: I also noticed that the list numbers are left-justified instead of right-justified. It took me some doing, but I found the answer. Look at the css code in code span::before for the details.

```css
code {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    background: lightseagreen;
    color:black;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    display: block;
}
code:before {
    counter-reset: listing;
}
code>span:not(.spr) {
    counter-increment: listing;
}
code span::before {
    content: counter(listing) " ";
    /* added these lines to right-justify the numbers
       and account for up to 4 digits wide */
    display:inline-flex;
    width: 2.75em;
    padding-right: .5em;
    justify-content: right;
    /* =================== */
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.spb {
    color:blue;
}
.spr:before {
    content:none !important;
}
.spr {
    color:red;
}
.spr2 {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<CODE>
<SPAN class="spb">//</SPAN> <SPAN class="spr">some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN class="spr2">some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
<SPAN>some code;</SPAN>
</CODE>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get that HTML from? We stopped using `<UPPERCASE>` tag-names in the late-1990s.

Comment: I have explained this before. I use uppercase for tags, lowercase for attributes. That is my preference. So, no, *we* didn't stop using uppercase in the 90s.

Comment: I've been writing HTML since HTML 2.0 back in the mid-90s. HTML is case-insensitive. <HTML> = <html> = <HtMl> = <hTmL>

Comment: Why does my question have a -2 in the upper left between the arrows?

Comment: I take it someone doesn't like the fact that I am independent enough to choose which case I prefer to use when writing HTML. Too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) and [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) elements only permit [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content).

The [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) and [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) elements are [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content), and if their children include at least one `<li>` element, [palpable content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#palpable_content).

Consider [escaping some of the html tag characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820460/5385381) so that the browser treats each code snippet as plain text and not html.

```html
<pre>
  <code>
      &lt;ol&gt;
        &lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;/ol&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
<pre>
    &lt;ol&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;/ol&gt;
</pre>
<code>
    &lt;ol&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;/ol&gt;
</code>
```

**Edit.**

If all you need is line numbers, perhaps this approach without ordered lists would pass validation.

```css
code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: lightseagreen;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  display: block;
}

code:before {
  counter-reset: listing;
}

code>.line {
  counter-increment: listing;
}

code .line::before {
  content: counter(listing) ". ";
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bold {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<code>
<span class="line">// WL_MAIN.C</span>
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="line">#include <span class="bold">"WL_DEF.H"</span></span>
<span class="line">#pragma hdrstop</span>
</code>
```

Comment: That would defeat the purpose. I am including a numbered list within the pre and code tags. eg. <pre><code><ol>

To change the tag identifiers would be to destroy the list,

Comment: I suppose it could be possible, maybe, with CSS, but HTML itself won't do it.  According to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp, "Text in a <pre> element is displayed in a fixed-width font, and the text preserves both spaces and line breaks. The text will be displayed exactly as written in the HTML source code."  Anything inside a <PRE></PRE> block is going to display exactly as shown. That is the point of it -- it is pre-formatted text.  If you prefer that the items in your list conform to the look of such pre-formatted text, you would want to use styles to specify the font face, etc.

Comment: If you look at my document (link in the question) you will see that your suggestion is much easier said than done. I will give consideration and see if I can figure out an alternative.

Comment: This is getting closer to a solution. However, I am using <span> to apply color to the places where code has been added or removed (commented). I'm not sure if using it the way you suggest won't conflict with that usage. I may have to create a special class for the color usage.

Comment: OK. I'm going to consider this answer to be the correct answer. Thanks for the help, Don 'FreihEitner' Eitner.

Comment: So far it is working, with one exception. On lines where I have a comment marker (//) there are 2 span tags. The first one colors the comment marker blue (and is also the one that has the line number) and the second one colors the commented text red. The second one shouldn't have a line number. I found a way to keep that one from incrementing, but I really would rather the line number not be there. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've updated the answer to add classes to the spans that represent an individual line.

Comment: Thanks for that. I found another way, but either will work. The issue I'm having now is that the line numbers are left-justified when I want them to be right-justified. The code I used with the <ol> tags doesn't work with the <span> tags. I have yet to find a workable solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the answer. I edited my question one last time to provide the answer.